# SSIS time in datetime reset to 0 after updating rows

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have 2 table, the second table must be update when the first table update. I'm using 2 lookup, one for filtering if there are any rows inserted to table 1 then it will be insert the new row in table 2, and the other for filtering if there are any change in table 1 rows by using modified date column to indicate it. The problem happened in the second lookup. When it detect there are any change in rows, it can update the changes in table 2 except the modified date column. the modified date column only update the date and the time will reset to 00.00.00.000. And when running the package that have only 1 row update it will show 4 rows no match output.I'm using OLE DB Command after the second Lookup to update it by using exec stored procedure.
Hope anyone will help me solve this
Thank You :)

Here's my query

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDistributionChannelTable] 
  @SrcDistributionChannelKey int,
  @SrcSourceKey int,
  @SrcDistributionChannelID int,
  @SrcDistributionChannelCode varchar(255),
  @SrcDistributionChannelText varchar(255),
  @Description varchar(MAX),
  @DistributionChannelKey int,
  @WorkstateKey int,
  @IsApproved int,
  @CustomFlag varchar(255),
  @ModifiedDate date,
  @UserID int,
  @UserName varchar(255),
  @StatusID int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

update Dim_SrcDistributionChannel
set 
 SrcSourceKey=@SrcSourceKey,
  SrcDistributionChannelID=@SrcDistributionChannelID,
  SrcDistributionChannelCode=@SrcDistributionChannelCode,
  SrcDistributionChannelText=@SrcDistributionChannelText,
  Description=@Description,
  DistributionChannelKey=@DistributionChannelKey,
  WorkstateKey=@WorkstateKey,
  IsApproved=@IsApproved,
  CustomFlag=@CustomFlag,
  ModifiedDate=@ModifiedDate,
  UserID=@UserID,
  UserName=@UserName,
  StatusID=@StatusID
where SrcDistributionChannelKey=@SrcDistributionChannelKey
END
```

In my ole db comment I just execute that stored procedure. 
Here's my ssis package design : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWAMsoiiJIVH2oA_6z5BFcmwpl-KvQNc/view?usp=sharing
I have the same column data type in that 2 tables, and data type for both modified column is date time.

Comment: You have to provide the OLE DB Command you are using, the columns data types (source and destination). Adding some screenshots will be helpful

Comment: As per the information, I think TRIGGER can solve your problem. if not then please share proper flow of info.

Comment: I've added the query above, n still don't have clue after searching till now

Comment: OMG I just realize, in my stored procedure I'm using only date, that's why the problem come from. After I change it to datetime, it's all great now